# HandsonTable: Unable to Retrieve Data with Alignment and Merge

Tags: node.js, handsontable

**Problem:**

**Alignment and Merged Cell** is not getting retrieved after storing and rendering the data..

Here are the steps I did:

**ON SAVING:**

As per the documentation, I'm saving the data by the following code:

```
var data = hot.getData()
```

I'm saving the above data into the database.

On saving, My table view is as below:

[image]

With Merged cells aligned Horizontal Center and Vertical-Middle.

**WHILE RETRIEVING:**

```
hot.loadData(data)
```

After retrieving, I'm getting the table like below:

[image]

As per the above image **ALIGNMENT AND MERGED CELLS ARE MISSING !!!**

***Kindly help me how to store the table formatting options also***

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to handle alignment options on retrieval of the HandsonTable from any Database or anyother datasource:

**Step-1: Create a method to handle the alignment options**

```
/*
    Method Description - Handles the alignment options for a single cell in the table.
*/
function handleAlignment(TD, row, column, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var _td = $(TD);
    var css = {};

    /* Extend the css object to set both Horizontal and Vertical alignment options */
    if (cellProperties) {
        /* Horizontal Alignment options. Set the style into the css object by extending it. */
        var className = cellProperties['className'];
        if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htCenter') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'text-align': 'center' });
        else if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htRight') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'text-align': 'right' });
        else if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htLeft') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'text-align': 'left' });
        else if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htJustify') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'text-align': 'justify' });

        /* Vertical Alignment options. Set the style into the css object by extending it. */
        if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htMiddle') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'vertical-align': 'middle' });
        else if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htTop') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'vertical-align': 'top' });
        else if (className != undefined && className != "" && className.indexOf('htBottom') != -1)
            css = $.extend({}, css, { 'vertical-align': 'bottom' });

        /* Apply the css style with horizontal and vertical options to the respective cell in the table. */
        _td.css(css);
    }
}
```

**Step-2: Add Handsontable event `beforeRenderer` in the Handsontable initialization:**

```
hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: [[""]],
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    filters: true,
    renderAllRows: true,
    dropdownMenu: true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    contextMenu: true,
    mergeCells: true,
    contextMenu: true,

    /* 
        Before Column has been rendered, apply the properties of each cell as 
        Alignment or anyother cellproperties
    */
    beforeRenderer: function (TD, row, column, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        handleAlignment(TD, row, column, prop, value, cellProperties)
    }
});
```

Here, `beforeRenderer` is the main thing to work on.